# axhspan set limits using coordinates

Tags: python, graph, colors, matplotlib

Is it possible to set the limits of the how far axhspan spand the x axis using coordinates rather than a value of 0-1? Usually the command takes:

`axhspan(ymin, ymax, xmin=0, xmax=1, **kwargs)`

I know that you can calculate the the 0-1 value for `xmin` and `xmax`from the coordinates, but it just seem a long winded way to o it?

**Example**:

I would like the blue shading to go from 0-100, white 100-200, blue 200-400.

Is the only way to do this either by converting to value of 0-1 or just adding the rectangle shape s as opposed to using `axhspan()`?

[image]

Comment: You could probably construct a custom transform for axhspan, that converts data units into figure units.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) with [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.add_patch).

For example:

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

plot(arange(0, 500), arange(0, 500))
gca().add_patch(Rectangle((100, 100), 200, 200)) # (x, y), width, height
show()
```

**NOTE** the 2nd, 3rd parameters of `Rectangle` constructor are `width`, `height` (not `x`, `y` position).

[image]